# Could someone edit the tags [proverb] and [colloquial] to become [proverbs] and [colloquialisms]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I like consistency in our tags, and to be consistent, we need to pluralize.  Unless we don't mind adjectival tags, in which case we can leave [colloquial] alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both tags have now been renamed.